# Stop use of Scientific Notation in Tooltips

Tags: tooltip

I have a list of pairs of values that I am plotting in a ListLinePlot. I can use the tooltip functionality fine but I want to stop them from displaying in scientific notation. I have tried the following

```
  DisplayData20Yr = {{2010, 1.49952026`*^6}, {2011, 
   1.82272254`*^6}, {2012, 2.01921445`*^6}, {2013, 
   2.28115586`*^6}, {2014, 2.77986072`*^6}, {2015, 
   3.18915846`*^6}, {2016, 3.1505870500000003`*^6}, {2017, 
   3.44300142`*^6}, {2018, 3.58399037`*^6}, {2019, 
   3.67522613`*^6}, {2020, 3.88522079`*^6}, {2021, 
   3.90061335`*^6}, {2022, 3.9293277800000003`*^6}, {2023, 
   3.90820965`*^6}, {2024, 3.9495397`*^6}, {2025, 
   3.6954160300000003`*^6}, {2026, 3.76539612`*^6}, {2027, 
   3.77579118`*^6}, {2028, 3.29648289`*^6}, {2029, 
   1.6678326400000001`*^6}}

DisplayData20YrNoScientific = 
  Map[NumberForm[N[#], ExponentFunction -> (Null &)] &, 
   DisplayData20Yr];

ListLinePlot[Tooltip[Table[DisplayData20Yr[[i]], {i, 20}]], 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}];

ListLinePlot[Tooltip[DisplayData20Yr], Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}];

ListLinePlot[
  Tooltip[DisplayData20Yr, Table[DisplayData20Yr[[i]], {i, 20}]], 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}];
```

The first plot works normally with the tooltips showing in scientific notation. The second plot works in the same way as the first plot. The third plot doesn't disply tooltips at all. When I then use the DisplayData20YrNoScientific data set all three plot do not display anything at all. No lines/points or tooltips. They are blank. In my understanding the third plot should work because tooltip can be used as Tooltip[expression,label].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is:

```
DisplayData20YrNoScientific = 
 Map[Tooltip[#, NumberForm[N[#], ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]] &, DisplayData20Yr]
```

So check that the tooltip works ok on the data:

[image]

Then plot it:

```
ListLinePlot[DisplayData20YrNoScientific, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Forgot to mention that your original `DisplayData20YrNoScientific`

```
DisplayData20YrNoScientific = 
  Map[NumberForm[N[#], ExponentFunction -> (Null &)] &, 
   DisplayData20Yr];
```

creates a list of strings so there is nothing for `ListLinePlot` to plot which is why it fails.